# AWS Amplify JS How to choose Cognito User Group?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a Cognito User Group with all my users and some groups which restrict access. A user can be member of multiple groups and the access rights should sum up. When logging into my application as a user, Amplify chooses the User Group and attached role of the group with the highest precedence. How can I choose another group in order to access other paths in my S3 bucket?